# How to use "two" counters in php in a array?

Tags: php

I get 2 arrays , the first is the list of id that user checked and the second is the users Id , i want to store in my database

```
array(2) { 
    ["id_users"]=> string(6) "2,5,6," 
    ["selected"]=> string(30) "1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1," 
}
```

I should store "1,2,2,2,2" to the user "2" and "1,2,2,2,2" to the user "5" and 
"2,1,1,1,1" to the user "6"

```
$list_checked = explode(",", $_GET['selected']);
//$class_name = explode(",", $_GET['class_name']);
$id_user = explode(",", $_GET['id_users']);
$count =  count($list_checked);
$count_id =  count($id_user);
$count_i = $count - 1;
$count_id_i = $count_id - 1;
$n = $count_i / $count_id_i ;
```

Comment: If there will always be the same number of selected https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: yes they will be always the same number of selected

Comment: i hope the strings are *not* what you store in the database, because that'd be **terrible** database design.

Comment: no , in fact it is a list of id too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code for you:

```
// NOTE, I removed last commas from strings in order to work correctly
$list_checked = explode(",", '1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1');
$id_user = explode(",", '2,5,6');
$count =  count($list_checked);
$count_id =  count($id_user);

// define chunk size as result of division
$chunk_size = $count / $count_id;

// get chunks
$chunks = array_chunk($list_checked, $chunk_size);

// ierate over user and get related chunk by key    
foreach ($id_user as $key => $value) {
    echo 'ID: ', $value, ', chunk: ', print_r($chunks[$key], 1);
}
```